# Finding particular solution to 1D - wave equation given general solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Given the general solution of the wave equation:

$\displaystyle u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \sin\left[ct\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi\right]\sin\left[\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) x\right]$

Find the particular solution given that:

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,0) = x$   for $0\leq x \leq 1$

**First Attempt:**

$\displaystyle u_t(x,0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nc\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\cdot \sin\left[\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) x\right] = x $

Then we find $b_n$ as shown below:

$b_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \pi x c(n+\frac{1}{2})) \cdot sin\big(\pi(n+\frac{1}{2}))\big)dx $

which simplifies to:

$2c(n+\frac{1}{2})\Big(\Big[-x\pi (n+\frac{1}{2})   \cdot   cos\big(\pi x(n+\frac{1}{2})\big)\Big]_0^\pi +  \pi (n+\frac{1}{2}) \int_0^\pi cos\big( x\pi (n+\frac{1}{2})\big)\Big)$

But is this the right way to go?

**Second Attempt:**

$\displaystyle u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \sin\left[ct\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi\right]\sin\left[\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) x\right]$

let $\alpha = (n+\frac{1}{2})$

$\displaystyle u(x,t)  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \cdot sin\big(ct\alpha \pi\big) \cdot sin\big(\pi\alpha x\big)$

$\displaystyle u_t(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \cdot c\pi \alpha \cdot cos\big(ct\alpha \pi\big) \cdot sin\big(\pi\alpha x\big)$

How do I calculate $b_n$ from here?

Me attempting to find $b_n$:

$\displaystyle b_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^1 \pi x c\alpha \cdot sin\big(\pi\alpha\big)dx $

goes to: 
$b_{n} = \frac{2}{(c \pi^{2} \alpha)} \int_{0}^{1} x \sin (\alpha \pi x) dx$

Comment: This problem was asked a couple of days ago (I remember because I edited the question) though I am unable to find it now. Which probably means it was deleted.

Comment: Yes my friend asked it however there was no answer, so he deleted it.

Comment: Any idea? Because we are struggling.

Comment: What does that mean :') Are you going to repost this question?

Comment: If anything, your orthogonality condition gives $$b_{n} = \frac{2}{c \pi^{2} (n + 1/2)} \int_{0}^{\pi} x \sin ((n+1/2)\pi x) dx$$ You multiplied the $c(n+1/2)\pi$ instead of dividing. Then integrate by parts. It won't be pretty though.

Comment: are the limits of the integral on $b_n$ correct?

Comment: Also should I first differentiate the summation and then find $b_n$ or find $b_n$ before differentiating?

Comment: You have to differentiate $u$ first, then find $b_{n}$, much as you have tried. And no, your limits are $0 \le x \le 1$ so you should be integrating from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Is b_n the cosine integral or sine integral?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49737/discussion-between-mattos-and-user2250537).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\displaystyle u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \sin\left[ct\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi\right]\sin\left[\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) x\right]$$
$$\displaystyle u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2}\left[ \cos\left[\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)(x-ct) \right]-\cos\left[\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) (x+ct)\right] \right]$$
 $$u(x,t) =f(x-ct)-f(x+ct)$$ 
Where $$f(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2} \cos\left[\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)(y) \right]$$
Now the boundary condition($\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,0) = x$) gives $f(x)= -\frac{x^2}{4c}+d$ which gives $$u(x,t) =\frac{(x+ct)^2}{4c} -\frac{(x-ct)^2}{4c}$$

Comment: Where did u get the boundary condition from?

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,0) = x$

Comment: how did u get $f(x)= -\frac{x^2}{4c}+d$ tho?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t) = -cf'(x-ct)-cf'(x+ct)$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,0) = -2cf'(x) = x$ now integrate.